# Regex to extract city and city code from a dynamic URL in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am storing the URL in location variale ,and which will be dynamic for ex.

1- https://abc.go.com/United_States,US/

2- https://abc.go.com/US/

3- https://abc.go.com/Uganda,UG/

4- https://abc.go.com/United_States,US

5- https://abc.go.com/

the URL's are totally dynamic ,
I was able to extract the state Code with following regex :-

`const cityCode =location.split(/(?=[A-Z][A-Z])/)[1].split('/')[0];`

//this will get two consecutive Uppercase characters and remove "/" in the end if present

Is there any possible regex to extract the country and State Code in a single variable if present in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group with an optional part for the first part and the comma

```
https?:\/\/\S+?\/((?:\w+,)?[A-Z][A-Z])
```

- `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol with optional s
- `\S+?\/` Match 1+ non whitespace chars as least as possible
- `(` Capture **group 1** (Which is accessed by `m[1]` in the example code)

  - `(?:\w+,)?` Optionally match 1+ word characters and a comma
  - `[A-Z][A-Z]` Match 2 uppercase chars
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rFNERg/1)

```js
const pattern = /https?:\/\/\S+?\/((?:\w+,)?[A-Z][A-Z])/;
[
  "https://abc.go.com/United_States,US/",
  "https://abc.go.com/US/",
  "https://abc.go.com/Uganda,UG/",
  "https://abc.go.com/United_States,US",
  "https://abc.go.com/"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(pattern);
  console.log(m ? m[1] : "no match");
});
```

Or if it is the part after the first forward slash

```
https?:\/\/[^\s\/]+\/((?:\w+,)?[A-Z][A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7y5zEP/1)

Comment: Just like this I have some strings in my url which has "-" in it for ex:-
1-

Comment: @Rupam can you give an example url with the hyphen?

Comment: Just like this I have some strings in my url which has "-" in it for ex:-
1-"https://abc.go.com/home-page/save/1-2/United_States,US/",      //need 1-2 from this
2-"https://abc.go.com/home-page/Treat/15-year/United_States,US/", //need 15-year from this
3-2-"https://abc.go.com/home-page/Treat/United_States,US/" //need nothing from here

how can I acheive this, also if you could tell me where to learn how to make these regex expressions

Comment: @Rupam You might do it like this https://regex101.com/r/IDfP8B/1 or like this https://regex101.com/r/RlTL7A/1

Comment: /(?:(\d[^\/]*)\/)/ this  works, but I am not able to understand this , can you please explain how it finds the string.

Comment: @Rupam That pattern can also be written without the surrounding non capture group `(\d[^\/]*)\/` It captures in group 1 a single digit and optional chars except a `/` Then, outside of the group, it matches a `/` You can read about capture groups [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), here about [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) the part with `[^` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
urls = ['https://abc.go.com/United_States,US/',
  'https://abc.go.com/US/',
  'https://abc.go.com/Uganda,UG/',
  'https://abc.go.com/United_States,US',
  'https://abc.go.com/'
];
urls.forEach(url => {
  console.log(url.match(/.*:\/\/.*?\/(.*)/m)[1].replace(/\/$/, ''))
});
```

Comment: can you pls tell what each expression does in this query

Answer (score 1):

```
var pathName = location.pathname;
var countryCode = (pathName.split('/')).length!= 0 ? pathName.split('/')[1].split(',') : [];
console.log(countryCode);


// if the Window URL is - "https://test.org/United_States,US" then result is - ["United_States", "US"]

// if the Window URL is - "https://test.org/United_States" then result is - ["United_States"]
```

Comment: there are multiple "/" present in the URL , url may look like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66668552/regex-to-extract-city-and-city-code-from-a-dynamic-url-in-react and also the position of country and country code is not fixed